# Downloadable Product import creates double entries in `downloadable_link` and `downloadable_link_price` tables

Tags: magento2, multistore, downloadable, download-link, product-import

I have imported downloadable products using Magento 2's default import flow with CSV.

To import it to different stores I have to add row per store. However, it creates duplicate entries in `downloadable_link` and `downloadable_link_price` tables. I think this is redundant.

Or how can I use **default stores'**(first store) attribute's value in the second store as I want to change ***some attributes only***?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by rewriting the file's `\Magento\DownloadableImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\Downloadable.php` function `parseOptions`  by `prefrence`.

like

```
    protected function parseOptions(array $rowData, $entityId)
    {
        if($rowData["store_view_code"] == "default" ){
            parent::parseOptions($rowData, $entityId);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```